# A using block, with an object initializer block in the constructor

Tags: c#

If you **call a constructor** from a within a **using statement** the object is automatically disposed is wrapped it with a try/catch block. That is an object initializer block in the constructor.

But what becomes with member types that are initialized in the same statement? e.g:

```
  class TypeThatThrowsAnException 
  {
       public TypeThatThrowsAnException() 
       {
           throw new Exception();
       }
  }

  using (SomeDisposable ds = new SomeDisposable() {
       MemberThatThrowsAnException m = new TypeThatThrowsAnException()
  })
  {
       // inside using statement
       ds.doSomething();
  }
```

What happens with `MemberThatThrowsAnException` when it throws an exception when SomeDisposable is initialized, i.e., the code block is executed?

And does it make any difference if we call those members constructors **outside** the scope of the `using` block?

```
  class TypeThatThrowsAnException 
  {
       public TypeThatThrowsAnException() 
       {
           throw new Exception();
       }
  }

  class SomeClass 
  {
       public static TypeThatThrowsAnException StaticMember 
       {
          get
          {
               return new TypeThatThrowsAnException();
          }
       }
  } 

  using (SomeDisposable ds = new SomeDisposable() {
       MemberThatThrowsAnException = SomeClass.StaticMember
  })
  {
       // inside using statement
       ds.doSomething();
  }
```

In some scenarios this can be pretty nice and readable, but I would like to know if thare are any **caveats or pitfalls** in this way. Or that it is a **no-go all the way**. *Besides that you need to keep the readability in mind.*

Comment: Did you mean to have a using statement and *then* a separate block? Your code isn't very clear at the moment.

Comment: @Jon: I believe the OP means to have a using block, with an object initializer block in the constructor statement. I was confused by the two pairs of curly braces too :P

Comment: @Tomas: Yes, I hadn't worked it out properly before. I have now :)

Comment: I already know by now that readability is the main issue here, however.. ;)

Comment: @Caspar: It doesn't help that it looks like you're trying to declare a new variable (`m`) within the object initializer. The code currently posted wouldn't compile.

Comment: @Jon, thank you m is removed, (should do this from VS instead of plain typing here (really gets messy ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Object initializers are in *some* sense a red herring here... but they're one example of where a problem is avoidable.

The object isn't "guarded" by the `using` statement until the resource acquisition expression has completed normally. In other words, your code is like this:

```
SomeDisposable tmp = new SomeDisposable();
tmp.MemberThatThrowsAnException = new TypeThatThrowsAnException();

using (SomeDisposable ds = tmp)
{
    // Stuff
}
```

That's more obviously problematic :)

Of course the solution is to assign the property *inside* the `using` statement:

```
using (SomeDisposable ds = new SomeDisposable())
{
    MemberThatThrowsAnException = new TypeThatThrowsAnException();
    // Stuff
}
```

Now we're only relying on the constructor of `SomeDisposable` to clean up after itself *if* it ends up throwing an exception - and that's a more reasonable requirement.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but **using** statement is implemented with a try/finally, so even if after construction time (type initializer) some exception is thrown, IDisposable.Dispose method will be always called. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Matias: It only enters the try block *after* resource acquisition has succeeded - so it wouldn't help here. Note that we're talking about object initializers, not type initializers - very different things.

Comment: I see, BTW it was a lapsus: I was talking about _object_ initializers.

Comment: for the first snippet - what about disposing of `tmp`? will it be disposed by a reference from `ds`? is `ds` need to be disposed also?

Comment: @anatol: Unless `SomeDisposable` is a struct, `tmp` and `ds` refer to the same object. It doesn't matter how that object is disposed (i.e. via which variable) - it's important that it *is* disposed.

Comment: okay, is that statement truly for reference types and value types?

Comment: @anatol: I don't know what you mean by "that statement". (I would note that it's extremely unusual for value types to implement `IDisposable` though...)

Comment: I meant _your_ statement (sentence, proposition) in comment. sorry, I missed _unless_. nvm

Answer (score 2):

Find [this post](http://ayende.com/blog/3810/avoid-object-initializers-the-using-statement) on Ayende's blog on the subject. It's about object initializers in `using` statements but it seems somehow related to your question.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, your SomeDisposable class has a property of type TypeThatThrowsAnException, that you're initializing as you instantiate the SomeDisposable - yes ?

using () i.e. the Dispose pattern is a short-hand that actually emits this: -

```
SomeDisposable ds = null;

try
{
    ds = new SomeDisposable();
}
finally
{
    if (ds != null)
        ds.Dispose();
}
```

So if the constructor for your type throws an exception, control will immediately pass to the finally block.

Comment: No, that's not the right translation - because you've got the `SomeDisposable` constructor call within the try block. It's not. It's *before* the try block. See section 8.13 of the C# 4 spec.

Comment: Noted, thanks Jon. That's here btw if anyone wants it - http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=7029