# How To Execute SqlQuery on Button Click (C#)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I need to change my SQL table's name when users click the buttons. I just found that T-SQL code, it worked but with steps;

1. *Right Click Database and Add New Query (on SQL Server Object Explorer)*
2. *Write tsql code and run (**sp_rename "old_name","new_name"**)*

I just want to how can I do this with a button, I mean, when I click the button my table's name will be change.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can execute database commands, [maybe start here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples)

Comment: The biggest you have by far is this "I need to change my sql table's name when users click the buttons". Changing table names on the whim of a user is a very clear indication that something has gone terribly wrong in the design of your application.

Comment: @Crowcoder i didn't find it. could you help me more pls? i saw many examples but all of them about insert,update and delete. i ve never seen my solution

Comment: @SeanLange I save some datas about the user's product property. I create new table when the user create new product. if user want to change his product's property name, should change it's sql table name?

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried so far.

Comment: That just sounds truly awful. How are you going to query any number of tables? Why is each product in a different table? Again, the problem isn't changing table names, it is the design of your data. Products should be stored in a single table.

Comment: @PaulF actually there is no code, i didnt do anything. i just connect to my database.

Comment: Well there is some code you can show as a starting point - it would give us an indication of what libraries you are using. But please take note of what we are saying about the design of your database - if you proceed this way you are like to have major problems in the future.

Comment: @SeanLange this products have different properties for example, product 1 has 4 columns and products 2 has 10 columns, how can i keep this on same table? maybe in next product n will be 20 columns? I am new at this and accualy i dont know well.

Comment: Consider how unwieldy your design will be when there are 10,000 products. A table for each product is never going to work. This is where you can leverage a partial EAV pattern. But honestly if you a really new to databases this project is probably over your head. You would need a table for products to capture the shared data for all products. Then an EAV extension to hold the individual properties that are unique to that product. I would suggest you get some help from a consultant to design this as it sounds like you need some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an sql command like below. However, I'm not sure why you want to rename a table every time a user presses a button.

**EDIT:** Updated to fix the SQL connection being out of scope. Looked at this too early in the morning. Thanks, Richardissimo, for pointing that out! You're also absolutely correct in saying you shouldn't swallow the exception.

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection("connectionString")
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_rename")
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure,
            Parameters =
            {
                new SqlParameter("@old_name", "oldtablename"),
                new SqlParameter("@new_name", "newtablename")
            },
            Connection = conn
        })
        {
            sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }   
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message.Trim());
    }
    finally
    {
        if(conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked, new SqlParameter("@objname", "oldName"),
                new SqlParameter("@newname", "newName")
i use it like that. thanks...

Comment: A couple of comments: the `finally` refers to the `conn` variable which is out of scope. I wouldn't recommend doing a try...catch which swallows the exception (I'd suggest removing the try..catch..finally from the answer). The use of object initializer compromises the `using` variable, putting it at risk, as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6568096/a-using-block-with-an-object-initializer-block-in-the-constructor).

Comment: Just noticed the edit (you would need to tag a message if you wanted me to notice). You don't need the `finally`, or anything in it because the implicit Dispose as it exits the connection's `using` block (which is missing a close bracket) will close the connection. The object initializer issue is still there and the unrequested and undesirable try catch is still there.